# Watson Visual recognition API

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson, visual-recognition

I am familiar with watson API key visual recognition :

```
visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3('2016-05-20', api_key=param)
```

with param as my api key.

this Api Call is nice to recognize forms. But Is it possible to get the positions of the elements that are recognized ? I do not see it in the API documentation. I see this is possible for face detection, but let say, I have a dog on my picture, how can I have the postions of this dogs ?

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/) is the API reference

Comment: It is not possible with Watson API.

Comment: @ Tomasz Plaskota : is that something that is under roadmap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service works by using a collection of classifiers, each classifier is a single tag only and must be trained with it's own sets of positive and negative images. Try to create smaller sub-images out of one image containing multiple entities.

See one [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEs1imQmk-Y&feature=youtu.be) to verify how it works.

[Fork](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/Visual-Recognition-Tile-Localization) on Github.

Comment: I will upvote your response and mark my question as answered. However, I would like to have the Python way to do this ( not the node ).

Comment: Here have some example to use with [Python](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/watson/2016/09/power-visual-recognition-use-watson-identify-hand-cards/). I show one example with Node because have how to do what you want, the logic is the same, you'll just did the same with other programming language

Comment: Thanks for this. I already do some advanced usage of visual rec and python I really needed the localisation of the position using python language. I will have have a look.